# How to solve duplication issues in d.ts files between two libs?

Tags: typescript, types, node-modules, vite

I am using [vite](https://vitejs.dev/) and [vite svgr plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-svgr)

and I get the following error when I try to build my app. It seems there are two same "src" declarations in both libs. Can I somehow solve this issue without excluding these libs from my dependencies?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exclude` attribute of `tsconfig.json` to solve this issue

```
{
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Note: You can even use `include` to specify the files for typescript.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html